# ASP.NET Core 7 MVC : custom SignInmanager IsSignedIn is always false

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, identity, .net-7.0

I am developing an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC web application. I am using Entity Framework code-first. All my code seems to work. I can add migrations, update database and run my web application.

Upon login, my custom `SignInManager` is called and returns a successful `SignInResult`. However in any view, where I use `@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))`, this is always false.

Here's some of my code:

Custom `SignInManager`:

```
public class LookupSigninManager : SignInManager<IdentityUser>
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
    private readonly ActiveDirectoryService _activeDirectoryService = new();

    public LookupSigninManager(
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, 
        IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, 
        IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser> claimsFactory, 
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, 
        ILogger<SignInManager<IdentityUser>> logger, 
        IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes, 
        IUserConfirmation<IdentityUser> confirmation,
        IUserRepository userRepository) 
        : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemes, confirmation)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public override async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
    {
        var dto = await _userRepository.Get(userName);

        if (dto == null) 
            return SignInResult.Failed;

        var user = _activeDirectoryService.GetUser(userName, password);
        var result = user != null ? SignInResult.Success : SignInResult.Failed;

        return await Task.FromResult(result);
        // This always succeeds and returns a SignInResult.Success
    }
}
```

`Login.cshtml.cs`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            // . . . . this uses my LookupSigninManager and always succeeds
        }
}
```

`program.cs` - I suspect that the issue is in here:

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataContextConnection");
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("KS.TestLookup.Web"));
    });

    builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(o =>
        {
            o.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 128;
            o.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
            o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        })
        .AddSignInManager<LookupSigninManager>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        
    builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o =>
    {
        o.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    });

    // Settings
    var sm = new SettingsService();
    var settings = sm.LoadSettings<AppSettings>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<AppSettings>(_ => settings);

    // Logging
    var logger = new AppLogger(new AppLoggerConfig
    {
        LogFilePath = settings.LogFilePath,
        ShowLogLevel = true,
    });
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAppLogger>(_ => logger);
    builder.Services.AddScoped<ILayerRepository, LayerRepository>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped(_ => ProductionMapper.Create());
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(); //options => options.Filters.Add<ErrorFilter>());
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    app.MapRazorPages();

    app.Run();
```

I have spent the day pretty much searching and trying a lot of suggested flavours of DI in `program.cs` but nothing has worked for me.

I'd be very grateful if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Why you are using ` return await Task.FromResult(result);` ?

Comment: Good point, early days of code base and all that. Havn't started refactoring yet.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `PasswordSignInAsync` method like below, and you could fix the issue.

```
public override async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
{
    var dto = await _userRepository.Get(userName);

    if (dto == null) 
        return SignInResult.Failed;

    var user = _activeDirectoryService.GetUser(userName, password);

    if (user != null)
    {
        return await base.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, isPersistent, lockoutOnFailure);
    }
    else
    {
        return SignInResult.Failed;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had tried this and it didn't work.  What I did to get things working was to start a new Web app from scratch and scaffold Identity first.  Then bring all nuget packages down to lowest common version.  Then setup my DI.  Then write my custom SignInManager. Then change my DI to consume that.  Seems to be working now.